# Using Html.LabelFor to display human readable label?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 and I'm struggling to understand how can I use the Html.LabelFor helpet method.

Assuming I have a model:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, if I write:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
```

What I get on the page is "FirstName". But I don't want that because it's not user-friendly. I want it to be "First Name".

How do I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just like this:

```
public class Person
{
  [DisplayName("First Name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

[System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx)

You should also check out [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) for some incredibly helpful validation attributes like `[Range(0, 100)]`, `[StringLength(100)]`, `[Required]` and more.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan Taylor's answer is the easiest. Another answer would be to create a custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, which gets the property name and splits it using some string helper. Manning's ASP.NET MVC2 in Action (2nd Edition) has an example of this in Chapter 15.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
```